# Android 5.x: Undefinable IllegalArgumentException (with GoogleMap) which causes 'Application Not Responding' crash

Tags: android, google-maps, illegalargumentexception, android-anr-dialog

I'm facing an issue with Android 5.x version. It is working fine in Android 4.x.

The View where it crashes contains a GoogleMap within a ScrollView. If I do not initialize the map, everything works fine. If I initialize, sometimes the app crashes or freezes, and I get the following error (same error from several devices in Hockey, Android 5.0 - Androdi 5.1.1):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.os.Parcel.nativeAppendFrom(Native Method)
    at android.os.Parcel.appendFrom(Parcel.java:446)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1300)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
    at android.location.Location.writeToParcel(Location.java:912)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1363)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1268)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2919)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3296)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The initialization of the map shouldn't be the problem, but problem also does not occur, if I don't call the "draw route on map" function. Sequence is the following

1. Start Activity and initialize the map
2. Place a custom marker on the map
3. get route from user position to outlet  //<--CRASH
4. zoom map to show user position route and outlet

   ```
   private void initializeMap() {
       if (googleMap == null) {

           scrollableMapFragment = ((ScrollableMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(R.id.retailer_detail_map));

           googleMap = scrollableMapFragment.getMap();

           // check if map is created successfully or not
           if (googleMap == null) {
               //show error
           } else {

               scrollableMapFragment
                       .setListener(new ScrollableMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onTouch() {
                               parallaxScrollView
                                       .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                           }
                       });

               googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
               googleMap.setLocationSource(this); //This is required for balancing power and (low) battery usage!!!
               googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
               googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

               placeOneMapMarker(customType);
           }
       }
   }

     private void placeOneMapMarker(CustomType marker) {
       LatLng latLng = null;
       GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate;
       MarkerOptions marker = null;
       geoCoordinate = marker.getGeoCoordinate();
       latLng = new LatLng(geoCoordinate.getLatitude(),
               geoCoordinate.getLongitude());


       marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
       // some more custom configurations...

       BitmapDescriptor icon = null;
       icon = iconManager.getShrinkedMapMarker(nRKER);

       marker.icon(icon);
       // adding marker
       googleMap.addMarker(marker);

       //CRASH!!!! if we uncomment this, everything works as expected
       showRoute();

   }


   private void showRoute(){
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           try {
               routeFromPosition = new LatLng(locationDao.getCurrentLocation().getLatitude(), locationDao.getCurrentLocation().getLongitude());
               routeToPosition = new LatLng(outlet.getAddress().getGeoCoordinate().getLatitude(),
                       outlet.getAddress().getGeoCoordinate().getLongitude());

               GoogleMapRoute googleMapRoute = new GoogleMapRoute();

               Document doc = googleMapRoute.getDocument(routeFromPosition, routeToPosition, GoogleMapRoute.MODE_DRIVING);
               directionPoint = googleMapRoute.getDirection(doc);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       if (directionPoint != null && directionPoint.size() > 0) {
                           showRoute();
                       } else {
                           zoomToOutletPosition();
                       }
                   }
               });
           } catch (Exception e) {
               //handle error
           }
       }
   }).start();
   ```

   }

And here s some logcat which looks like memory-leak?

```
07-29 17:41:02.016      892-892/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ Build: samsung/kltexx/klte:5.0/LRX21T/G900FXXU1BOE5:user/release-keys
    Hardware: MSM8974
    Revision: 14
    Bootloader: G900FXXU1BOE5
    Radio: unknown
    Kernel: Linux version 3.4.0-4920185 (dpi@SWDD6122) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 15 16:40:14 KST 2015
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kltexx/klte:5.0/LRX21T/G900FXXU1BOE5:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '14'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 30354, tid: 30371, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> app.package.name <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7b35f752
    r0 b40cc17c  r1 aeea30e0  r2 9ac4cbb0  r3 00000000
    r4 44726579  r5 9ac4cbb0  r6 b40cc17c  r7 6e616c2f
    r8 696c616e  r9 af3b8800  sl 00000000  fp b40cc208
    ip b6b77e14  sp b40cc178  lr b6b6473d  pc b6b6bae6  cpsr 200b0030
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000100000004
    d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000147389caaf68
    d8  41dfffffffc00000  d9  c1e0000000000000
    d10 43e0000000000000  d11 c3e0000000000000
    d12 df0000005f000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 ffffffff9ac4cbb0  d17 65522f6665722f67
    d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000060000000
    d20 0000000060000000  d21 0000000000000004
    d22 9fde15409fde1400  d23 9fde17c09fde1680
    d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 0001000100010001  d27 0002000200020001
    d28 0000000003205f58  d29 00000000007ffaf0
    d30 0800080008000800  d31 0800080008000800
    scr 80000011
    backtrace:
    #00 pc 0001fae6  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+29)
    #01 pc 0001fb19  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+26)
    #02 pc 0001fb3b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
    #03 pc 00083267  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #04 pc 00017451  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
    stack:
    b40cc138  b40cc1a8  [stack:30371]
    b40cc13c  b4b85fb5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+12)
    b40cc140  b40cc164  [stack:30371]
    b40cc144  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc148  b40cc17c  [stack:30371]
    b40cc14c  b40cc228  [stack:30371]
    b40cc150  b40cc240  [stack:30371]
    b40cc154  b6b6473d  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    b40cc158  b6b7807c  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    b40cc15c  b6b6d8db  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::ProcessState::self()+94)
    b40cc160  b40cc17c  [stack:30371]
    b40cc164  b6b780d4  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    b40cc168  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc16c  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc170  b40cc17c  [stack:30371]
    b40cc174  b6b6bad7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+14)
    #00  b40cc178  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc17c  aeec7100
    b40cc180  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc184  00000000
    b40cc188  b4dfd034
    b40cc18c  b40cc228  [stack:30371]
    b40cc190  b40cc240  [stack:30371]
    b40cc194  b6b6bb1d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+30)
    #01  b40cc198  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc19c  b40cc1cc  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1a0  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc1a4  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc1a8  b40cc1f0  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1ac  b6b6bb3f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+8)
    #02  b40cc1b0  9ac4cbb0
    b40cc1b4  b6dca26b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #03  b40cc1b8  000003e8
    b40cc1bc  74916453  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
    #04  b40cc1c0  70c9ff98  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
    b40cc1c4  b40cc340  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1c8  00000001
    b40cc1cc  70c9f630  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
    b40cc1d0  00000000
    b40cc1d4  b40cc1f0  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1d8  b4dfd034
    b40cc1dc  b40cc228  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1e0  b40cc240  [stack:30371]
    b40cc1e4  00000000
    b40cc1e8  b40cc208  [stack:30371
07-29 17:41:02.016      892-892/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ processName:app.package.name
07-29 17:41:02.016      892-892/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ broadcastEvent : app.package.name SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
07-29 17:41:02.016      257-257/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ id=1053 createSurf (49x49),1 flag=4, Application Error: app.package.name
```

Comment: If your code is crash at `showRoute();` , can you show the code about that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just solved our issue with the help of Androids `StrictMode`

Adding the following to your `Activity` `onCreate()` gives you more detailed informations about crashes and policy violations. One of the violation was the key to our crash, but that nothing to do with the code I posted (issue occured as a side-effect)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectDiskReads()
                    .detectDiskWrites()
                    .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build());
        //...
}
```

API-Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: Could you explain the actual issue? It might be helpful to others (myself included)